# How to print multiple results in row

Tags: java, jsf, tomahawk

I have a requirement to print my list in two columns along with pagination.

I am not able to figure out how will I get 2 records at a time from the list set in the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the [DataModel](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html). See the question [Multiple rows per record in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355699/multiple-rows-per-record-in-jsf/356354) This is the opposite of what you want, but the principle is the same.

Your model implementation could return a row level bean that exposes an object for each column.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works:
Make a new String. Loop your content and add them to the string one by one.

E.g

```
ArrayList setA = new ArrayList();
ArrayList setB = new ArrayList();

//add stuff to both arraylist
String result = "";

for (int i = 0; i < setA.size(); i++)
{
    result = setA.get(i) + "\t" + setB.get(i);    
}    
System.out.println(result);
```

hope i am answering your questions.